# Delete object references to selected object by it's ID

Tags: javascript

I have a node system, which stores a bunch of nodes that are connected to other nodes. The data is structured like this:

```
[
 {"id":0,"x":1,"y":2, "linksTo":[1]},
 {"id":1,"x":3,"y":4, "linksTo":[0,2,3]},
 {"id":2,"x":5,"y":6, "linksTo":[1,4]},
 {"id":3,"x":3,"y":10,"linksTo":[1,4]},
 {"id":4,"x":5,"y":12,"linksTo":[2,3]}
]
```

What I'm trying to do is delete a certain node, and all references to that in the other nodes that might be "linked" to it based on its ID.

I've gotten to the point where I can get the node i need using this function:

```
function getNode(id, y){
    var x;
    if(y){ x = id; }   
    if(x && y){
        var nodeAtPos = false; 

        Object.keys(paths.list).forEach(function(i){
            if(paths.list[i].x == x && paths.list[i].y == y){
                nodeAtPos = paths.list[i];
                return false;
            }
        return true;
        });        
    return nodeAtPos;
    } 
    return paths.list[id];
}
function deleteNode(x,y){
    var obj = getNode(x,y);
//need to delete obejct and delete key references in other objects that were connected to it
}

deleteNode(5,12);
```

The end result would look like this in my data structure:

```
[
 {"id":0,"x":1,"y":2, "linksTo":[1]},
 {"id":1,"x":3,"y":4, "linksTo":[0,2,3]},
 {"id":2,"x":5,"y":6, "linksTo":[1]}, //changed
 {"id":3,"x":3,"y":10,"linksTo":[1]}, //changed
]
```

But as you can see in my data strucutre, if I simply delete it, I still have a few nodes that `linksTo` to it that I need to clean up. Otherwise they will be linked to non existant nodes.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you expect the array to look like after calling `deleteNode(5,12);`

Comment: given the node's ID, iterate over your array, and delete this ID from each element's `linksTo`

Comment: @DominicTobias thank you for the suggestion, see question edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `iterate` each object and do the following operations:

- Check if the `node` has its link to it. If so remove it from its
  `linkTo`.
- During the iteration, keep track of the `index` of the node which has
  its `id` as the node to be deleted.
- Once the iteration is done, `remove` the node from the array.

Code:

```
var x = [
 {"id":0,"x":1,"y":2, "linksTo":[1]},
 {"id":1,"x":3,"y":4, "linksTo":[0,2,3]},
 {"id":2,"x":5,"y":6, "linksTo":[1,4]},
 {"id":3,"x":3,"y":10,"linksTo":[1,4]},
 {"id":4,"x":5,"y":12,"linksTo":[2,3]}
];

var index = -1;
var toDel = 2;
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(x[i]["linksTo"].indexOf(toDel) != -1){
        x[i]["linksTo"].splice(x[i]["linksTo"].indexOf(toDel),1);
    }
    if(x[i]["id"] == toDel){index = i;}
}
if(index != -1){
    x.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: There is one issue here in that you're deleting based on array position. Where as my getNode returns the object by a property called ID. Is there a way to get the object's array position without having to iterate through my data twice?

Comment: The iteration is not happening twice, here. Just iterate once over all the objects, remove the `id` from the `linksTo` property of each object, if present, at the same time check if the node which is to be deleted is found, keep track of its `index`. Then remove the `Object` from the `array` at last by its index.

Comment: Note: browser support for indexOf is limited, it is not supported in IE7-8.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way, but to update the linksTo value for the rest of elements

```
var deletedId = 4;
var arr = [
 {"id":0,"x":1,"y":2, "linksTo":[1]},
 {"id":1,"x":3,"y":4, "linksTo":[0,2,3]},
 {"id":2,"x":5,"y":6, "linksTo":[1,4]},
 {"id":3,"x":3,"y":10,"linksTo":[1,4]},
];

for (var i=0 ; i  < arr.length ; i++ ) {
   var node = arr[i];
   var newRef = [];
   for (var l=0 ; l < node.linksTo.length; l++) { // l is an index for links
     if (node.linksTo[l] != deletedId)
       newRef.push(node.linksTo[l])
   }
   node.linksTo = newRef;  // assign new array
}
```